# Concatenate comma delimited information from two columns into one

Tags: powerbi, concatenation, delimiter, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to concatenate information from two columns into one column in PowerBI. If all the cells were the same, this would be really straight forward. The issue is that I am working with address information that is extracted from a records database with an interesting set-up that I have no control over.

The PowerBI report I have built is used to compare the records database to an online spreadsheet that technicians are using to mark changes that need to be made to the records based on changes they make in a map database. The comparison is done in a PowerBI merged table between records database and the spreadsheet.

Most records are for only one address, while about 10% of the records have multiple address. Currently, the comparison report is telling us that the address do not match on these 10%, even if the addresses are a match.

Data Example of current result only using concatenate:

| Row Number | Street Number | Street Name | Concatenated Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | Harvey St | 234 Harvey St |
| 2 | 246 | Malone Ave | 246 Malone Ave |
| 3 | 872, 954 | Bluebell Way, Main St | 872, 954 Bluebell Way, Main St |
| 4 | 376, 3457, 78 | Harvey St, Bluebell Way, Malone Ave | 376, 3457, 78 Harvey St, Bluebell Way, Malone Ave |

This is what I am trying to achieve using Dax. So before someone say to split it in the Power Query and create more columns, I'd rather not since the number of address can vary, and I'm already at 46 columns including the ones below.

Data Example of the desired result:

| Row Number | Street Number | Street Name | Concatenated Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | Harvey St | 234 Harvey St |
| 2 | 246 | Malone Ave | 246 Malone Ave |
| 3 | 872, 954 | Bluebell Way, Main St | 872 Bluebell Way, 954 Main St |
| 4 | 376, 3457, 78 | Harvey St, Bluebell Way, Malone Ave | 376 Harvey St, 3457 Bluebell Way, 78 Malone Ave |

My thought is that maybe there is some way to use a delimiter with concatenating but I am not sure how.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me with solving this.

Comment: @horseyride with his magic delimiter formulas would help )))

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a similar need, although there may be simpler approaches I'm not aware of.  Basic steps were to convert the columns to Lists, Zip the Lists, Expand the List, Extract Values, then Group and combine the results.  Here's a bit more detail on each step I took:

1. Add Custom Column named [Custom] with this formula >

   Text.Split([Street Number], ",")
2. Add another Custom Column named [Custom.1] with this formula >

   Text.Split([Street Name], ",")
3. Add another Custom Column named [Custom.2] with this formula >

   List.Zip({[Custom], [Custom.1]})
4. Expanded [Custom.2], formula bar shows this:

   = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.2")
5. Extracted [Custom.2], formula bar shows this:

   = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom.2", {"Custom.2", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text})
6. Group on {"Row Number", "Street Number", "Street Name"}, but change the formula bar to use this function instead:

   = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Row Number", "Street Number", "Street Name"}, {"Concatenated Address", each Text.Combine([Custom.2], ","), type text})

Here is the full Advanced Editor:

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XY6xCsMwDER/5fCspbYTu2M7denUIYPJ4IKGgkmhtIH8fSQMjZNFoNO706VkToaMdV7mLX9mXvD4VgXbPlIyVlXfy7zn8p4Yl5mrhEZQ0okcgyWcO429lh8/uRQMeSFhX1N9IQj2N+H/dw1Stws9wfkuEEJsSxKOwU0rcaEh1X/AQ9zVHlc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Row Number" = _t, #"Street Number" = _t, #"Street Name" = _t, #"Concatenated Address" = _t]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Split([Street Number], ",")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Text.Split([Street Name], ",")),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each List.Zip({[Custom], [Custom.1]})),
#"Expanded Custom.2" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.2"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom.2", {"Custom.2", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Extracted Values", {"Row Number", "Street Number", "Street Name"}, {"Concatenated Address", each Text.Combine([Custom.2], ","), type text})
```

in
#"Grouped Rows"

Comment: Hey Ben M,

Thank you for helping me try to find a solution. It is so close. It's perfect except one thing I did not think about. Looking through the data there are some situations where there are multiple Address Numbers but only 1 Street name. 


Any suggestions on how to get that one street name to tie to each of the street numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`Split Columns into Rows` is your key... it is a long shoot to explain, therefore check the sample file and let me know if it works for you...

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oifzHiF5eSk4cNcZ_Zc3tL-p7JjaY-2_/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100599386090580961037&rtpof=true&sd=true)